# Android relative layout placement problems

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have been having problems creating a relative layout in XML for a list item to be used for a series of items in a ListView. I have tried for hours and am tearing my hair out trying to get it to look how I want but cannot get everything to appear in the correct spot and not overlap or mis-align. I can get the first image and next two textviews in place but cannot get the last textview and imageview.

I have attached a wireframe style image of how I am trying for it to look and was wondering if someone could help me out?

[image]

- The ImageView on the right is a set icon of the full height of the row with padding around it?
- The two TextViews take up the majority of the width. The Address textview has the possibility of the text being long so it may need to get truncated if it runs out of space, or ideally have the font size shrink?
- The next TextView will just hold a small string of max 5 characters.
- The last ImageView is a small arrow to imply that this list item is clickable for more infomation. It needs to be centred like shown.
- I would like if the icon, last textview, and last image always be in the same place/alignment down the list.

If someone could offer some assistance on this I would be so grateful.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone interested I managed to get this working. I know how much of a pain it is to go searching for an answer to a problem and it was never completely resolved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Icon"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Icon"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/distance"
    android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
    android:textSize="20dip"
    android:text="Name" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Icon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topLine"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/distance"
    android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:text="Address" />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/distance"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:text="100m" />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:src="@drawable/redarrow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a perfect answer because Name and Address's height is not the same (50% each of their parent).

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar (except the image on left)

It might help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TextView01"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/Birthday"
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
            <TextView
                android:text="1960-01-01"
                android:id="@+id/txtSubvalue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"></TextView>
        <TextView
            android:text="weeks"
            android:id="@+id/txtUnit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- <View
        android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01" /> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I might have to resort to using LinearLayout if I can't get this working. I have read though that using LinearLayout for list item rows and therefore having it replicated for each row create many unnecessary overheads whereas RelativeLayout does not. I will paste the link again if I can find it. Thanks for the answer though, it could end up being what I need.

Comment: I found the link: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/

And the comment: "This layout works but can be wasteful if you instantiate it for every list item of a ListView. The same layout can be rewritten using a single RelativeLayout, thus saving one view, and even better one level in view hierarchy, per list item."