# Android view problem - ImageView and Two TextView's

Tags: android, view, textview, imageview

I'm trying to position two TextView's to the right of an image view (note this is not in a list). I followed [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/) example which works but problems occur when I start to increase the text size and background of the TextView. Here the top text view seems to expand despite setting the height to wrap_content.

Looking at the example I don't really understand

> android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

and why the layout height is set to 26dip

> android:layout_height="26dip"

Here is my xml with the minor changes to layout_height which I thought would work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/secondLine" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@layout/rounded"
        android:textSize="20sp" android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@layout/rounded"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:padding="10dip" android:layout_margin="5dip" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the resulting image???

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

I just stumbled on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289096/android-relative-layout-placement-problems) which seems to work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="6dip">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Icon" android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:src="@drawable/addphoto" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/topLine" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Icon" android:background="@layout/rounded"
        android:padding="10dip" android:textSize="20sp" android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Name" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/bottomLine" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Icon" android:layout_below="@+id/topLine"
        android:padding="10dip" android:background="@layout/rounded"

        android:textSize="20sp" android:singleLine="true" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:text="Address" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The screenshot looks fine to me... how do you expect it to look exactly?

Comment: I don't want all the padding around the top text view. I want it to resemble the text view below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see that result because you have the following attributes on the textview: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"`.

The above attributes specify that the top must be aligned with the parent and the bottom must be just above the 'secondline' component.

I removed the above two attributes and did a few more changes to your layout to get to what I believe you want. See the layout below. I hope this layout achieves what you wish to obtain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:padding="6dip">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/icon"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="My Application" />
```